# How to prevent 'Send an email (V2)' message body area from automatically switching back to rich text editor mode?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

**Steps to recreate**

1. Click the `</>` icon to toggle message body area to code view , enter your HTML with links and dynamic variables, eg:

```
<p>
Some text here.  
<br>
<br>
Some dynamic content here.
<br>
<br>
Some links here (referencing variables) etc.  
<br>
<br>
</p>
```

2. Save and exit the flow.
3. Re-open the flow.
4. Message body area has switched to Rich Text Editor view and all the links and HTML are malformed
5. Click the `</>` icon to toggle message body area to code view , clean up the HTML and Save.
6. Steps 3-5 repeat forever.

**Question**

How to prevent [Send an email (V2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-an-email-(v2)) message body area from automatically switching back to rich text editor mode?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code within a Div and this should disable the button that returns it to Rich Text and should keep this on save as well.

```
<div>
<p>
Some text here.  
<br>
<br>
Some dynamic content here.
<br>
<br>
Some links here (referencing variables) etc.  
<br>
<br>
</p>
</div>
```

Also a [link to a post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-an-email-v2/td-p/285012) where others have utilised this method as well.